# DuplicateKeyException not being thrown in some circumstances

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two SQL tables, each with a compound key made of three different integer fields. I have added the code as follows to add a record to Table1.

```
try
{
    Table1 newRow = new Table1
    {
        DomainID = domainID,
        ConfigurationID = configID,
        ReasonID = reasonID
    };

    data.Table1.InsertOnSubmit(newRow);
    data.SubmitChanges();
}
catch(DuplicateKeyException)
{
    // Message to user about no duplicates allowed.
}
```

This works exactly how I have planned and catches an exception if the user is trying to add a duplicate row and I can show them a message etc. All is fine. However, the code I have for inserting to Table2 (which is almost identical, on a different Page using a different DataContext however),

```
try
{
    Table2 newRow = new Table2
    {
        DomainID = domainID,
        ConfigurationID = configID,
        DirectionID = directionID
    };

    data.Table2.InsertOnSubmit(newRow);
    data.SubmitChanges();
}
catch(DuplicateKeyException)
{
    // Message to user about no duplicates allowed.
}
```

does not throw a DuplicateKeyException but a SqlException. Not too much of a big-deal as I can still test

```
e.Number = 2627
```

on the caught SqlException but I'm just confused as to why it is working differently!?

Comment: Need to see Table1 and Table2 SQL DDL to tell how you've set up the fields and keys in your DB

Comment: Look at the DataContext. For some reason Table2 (LINQ side) is not aware of the constraint or not enforcing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a problem with the definition of your table 2. Specifically with the primary key column on it. Maybe it has a [Unique Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and that's why it throws an exception, but it is not certainly its primary key.